# Maintenance redirect Node.js on Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-503

I'm currently developing some websites with Node.js, but when I take it offline for maintenance etc. it shows me a 503 (an ugly one...)

It's on a host where I can run Node.js on given port (doh) and I need to place an htaccess file with a redirect to that port in the apache folder.

I've been googling a while, and I can't find it... Help?

.htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:*portno*/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:*portno*/$1 [P,L]
```

It's a shared hosting account with SSH access.

Apache Version  2.2.29
cPanel Version  11.48.0 (build 13)

Comment: Does your host support reverse proxying? You could set up a standalone app that runs on an internal port, and have your .htaccess redirect still to port 80, but on a different subdomain?

Comment: You mean a new Node.js app it redirects to if a 503 is gotten or....?
I kinda just want a good htaccess file that handles it...

Comment: Well the thing is .htaccess only works with Apache - and if you're hosting your Apache server in the same directory as Node, you'll get some really strange overlap. In the end though, what you really don't want is a maintenance page that runs on a port other than 80/443 unless you're proxying it up the chain.